# How do I use google play developer if my account is closed due to inactivity

Tags: google-play

I have this information on my google play console, and I lost any email what do I do?

```
This developer account has been closed due to inactivity, and can't be reactivated.
We've sent more information to the account owner's email address.
```

Is there a way I can reopen another account on this email address, or can I use a different email address.

Comment: Me, too. And I can do nothing to reactive my account.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a response I found from Google: [Google's Response](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/208102688/my-developer-account-was-closed-due-to-inactivity-but-we-have-an-active-app-how-do-i-get-access?hl=en)

Pasting text here for convenience and incase it gets "disabled" LOL!

> If an account is closed because of inactivity then I am afraid there
> is no way to recover it. A number of warnings are sent to the account
> owner before the account is closed.
>
> The dormant account policy does
> allows you to open a new account:
> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9899234
> but you will need to use a different account/email address.

You will also need to use a different Developer name when creating your new account, so if you used your real name you are tough out of luck and must now use a dev handle name, perhaps something like: JonDoeNotDeletedByGoogle.